# clearTimeout not working when called in if statement

Tags: javascript, cleartimeout

This code should run for 10 seconds before ending, however if you are running the function again before the 10 seconds are finished, it should clear theTimeout and start the 10 seconds over again

```js
  function start() {
    let counter = 0;
    let timeUp = true;
    let hello;
    setInterval(()=> {
      counter++
      console.log(counter)
    },1000);
    if (timeUp == false) {
      clearTimeout(hello)
      timeUp = true
      console.log('should run again with new clock')
      start()
    } else {
      console.log('new clock started')
      timeUp = false;
      hello = setTimeout(() => {
        timeUp = true
        console.log('end clock')
      }, 10000);
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `start()` again, this new function has no reference to `hello` or `timeUp`
Try it like this:

```js
let hello
let timeUp = true

function start() {
    let counter = 0;
    //let timeUp = true;
    //let hello;
    setInterval(()=> {
      counter++
      console.log(counter)
    },1000);
    if (timeUp == false) {
      clearTimeout(hello)
      timeUp = true
      console.log('should run again with new clock')
      start()
    } else {
      console.log('new clock started')
      timeUp = false;
      hello = setTimeout(() => {
        timeUp = true
        console.log('end clock')
      }, 10000);
    };
  };
  
  window.start = start
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your function `start`, `timeUp` is always set to `true`, and thus `clearTimeout` will never be called. The way you're doing things, you should make `timeUp` a global variable so the function has "memory" of if the time has been reached or not.

But why do you need to set two intervals? You're already keeping track of the number of seconds that have passed, so we can make use of that interval to determine when 10 seconds have passed. This simplifies things quite a bit, and allows us to get rid of the `timeUp` variable as well:

```
let interval;

function start() {
    let counter = 0;
    clearInterval(interval); // clear the previous interval
    interval = setInterval(() => { // set a new interval
        counter++;
        if (counter == 10) {
            console.log('end of clock');
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        console.log(counter);
    }, 1000);
}
```

This achieves exactly what you want. Whenever `start` is called, it cancels the previous interval and creates a new one. Once 10 seconds have passed, it clears the interval.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is kind of misleading. I think a better approach would be to have a Timer Object that you can start:

```js
function Timer() {
    var self = {
        // Declare a function to start it for a certain duration
        start: function(duration){
            self.counter = 0;
            self.duration = duration;
            clearTimeout(self.timeout); // Reset previous timeout if there is one
            console.log("New counter starting.");
            self.count();
        },
        // A function to count 1 by 1
        count: function(){
            console.log(self.counter);
            self.counter++;
            if(self.counter > self.duration){
                console.log('Time is up.');
            } else {
                self.timeout = setTimeout(self.count, 1000); // not over yet
            }
        }
        // and other functions like stop, pause, etc if needed
    };
    return self;
}

// Declare your Timer
var myTimer = new Timer();

// Start it on click
document.getElementById('start-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    myTimer.start(10);
}, true);
```

```html
<button id="start-btn">Start the timer</button>
```

Comment: This doesn't achieve what OP asked. Two calls to `myTimer.start` does not reset the timer.

Comment: @bejado True. I made an edit so you can start it multiple times